# Retrieving the ResourceId of a scaleable target

Tags: amazon-ecs

In the AWS Resource `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget`, how do I retrieve the value of `ResourceId` which is the unique resource identifier that associated with the scaleable target?

The format used in the ResourceId property is `service/cluster_name/service_name`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the ResourceId property should be in the form `service/<cluster_name>/<service_name>`.

Incidentally, (and to help future Googlers) the error message that you get when you use an incorrect `ResourceId` or `ScalableDimension` is:

> Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension

To achieve this in CloudFormation you can use a `Fn::Join` for the `ResourceId`. Here is a snippet of the Scalable target that I am using:

```
"ECSServiceScalableTarget": {
    "Type": "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget",
    "Properties": {
        "MaxCapacity": 5,
        "MinCapacity": 1,
        "ResourceId": { "Fn::Join" : ["/", [
            "service",
            { "Ref": "ECSCluster" },
            { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["ECSService", "Name"] }
        ]]},
        "RoleARN": { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:iam::", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":role/ApplicationAutoscalingECSRole"]]},
        "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
        "ServiceNamespace": "ecs"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the {"Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ "a", "b", "c" ] ]"} to get the value of the "ResourceId".